# What does "greater-than-equal" mark means in OpenCV mat class?

Tags: opencv

I got an **OpenCV** `pHash` code from following url:
https://gist.github.com/msly/bb0bff63914d54fed88f

And i want to port the code to **Java**.

But really what does

```
Mat mask = (dst >= imageMean[0]);
```

and

```
mask.at<uchar>(i, j) == 0 ? (hash[i*mask.cols + j] = '0') : 
(hash[i*mask.cols + j] = '1');
```

mean? Is there some java wrapper method for ">=", and the "at<uchar>"?

I found the up `">="` mask as

```
Core.compare(Mat, Scalar, Core.CMP_GE)
```

But while `imageMean` **is Scalar in java,** what's the `imageMean[0]` mean in C++ code?

Answer (score 4):

```
Mat mask = (dst >= imageMean[0]);
```

is a [MatExpr](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#gsc.tab=0).

Basically it is a element-wise comparison with respect to the scalar and giving out a matrix with **255** if the condition is satisfied and **0** if it is not.